# How do I interact with a contract using Gnosis Provider server-side? (in NodeJs)

Tags: gnosis-safe

I was trying to build an app on top of gnosis where users can interact with contracts directly from discord. Is there a way I can interact with a contract using gnosis provider?

I found out this example from the NPM package readme:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { useSafeAppsSDK } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-apps-react-sdk';
import { SafeAppProvider } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-apps-provider';

const App = () => {
  const { sdk, safe } = useSafeAppsSDK();
  const web3Provider = useMemo(() => new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(new SafeAppProvider(safe, sdk)), [sdk, safe]);

  // use provider with contracts

  return;
};

export default App;
```

I was trying this:

```
const { SafeAppProvider } = require("@gnosis.pm/safe-apps-provider");
const { SafeAppsSDK } = require("@gnosis.pm/safe-apps-sdk");
const p = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
  new SafeAppProvider(
    {
      safeAddress: "0x92e513510597aE747eAF5428B090e0229c639c4d",
      chainId: 4,
      threshold: 1,
      owners: ["rin:0x23302DA41ae4A69875321343D7ACA464a4E72DB2"],
    },
    SafeAppsSDK
  )
);
```

But it will obviously throw this error:

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

I could not find any examples where I could do this on the server side using the provider :(

Comment: why do you need a gnosis provider for a discord tool? this provider is meant to be used in the Safe App context.

Comment: for scripts/etc we have https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk